# Dictionaries - returning non zero values and corresponding index locations

Tags: python, dictionary

I have spent countless hours watching python dictionary tutorials but still cannot figure out how to return the desired result.

Given some list of grades (0 to 1 as floats) called variable `y`.
`y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0]`
I have a dictionary called `dic`.
`dic = {'pos':[ ], 'grds':[ ]}`

I want to return all non zero grades and corresponding positions in the list as the dictionary, `dic`, without modifying the `y` list. Assistance in solving is greatly appreciated but also want to understand the solution.

Comment: is this a homework?

Comment: Hmm... you can do this without using `dic['pos']`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? :-) Loops perhaps?

Comment: Looping over your list using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes this is an assignment, the dictionary is defined as stated and can't be altered so the returned result should be two different lists which are the "values" for the "keys" 'pos' and 'grds'. I am trying to teach myself Python in a weekend so understand I am still a newb. I have tried like 8 approaches, some based off of work I found for unrelated problems, one I wrote myself (obviously wrong) - for 'pos', 'grds' in dic.items() if y !=0

Comment: Ooh okay. Python in a weekend sounds pretty fast. :-) Doing `for 'pos', 'grds' in dic.items()` will *iterate through* the lists in your dictionary values (currently empty). So you might want to consider copying appropriate values into `dic['pos']` and `dic['grds']` first? Then try playing with your loop from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code for getting Output the way OP wants it:**

```
pos_grade = {'pos': [], 'grds': []}

y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82]

for i, x in enumerate(y):
   if x != 0.0:
       pos_grade['pos'].append(i)
       pos_grade['grds'].append(x)

print pos_grade
```

**Output:**

```
{'grds': [0.97, 0.82, 0.66, 0.9, 0.82], 'pos': [1, 5, 6, 9, 12]}
```

---

Below approaches can be used if one wants to just use a dictionary to get the grades and values.

```
pos_grade = {}

y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0]

i = 0
for x in y:
   if x != 0.0:
       pos_grade[x] = i
   i += 1

print pos_grade
```

**Output:**

```
{0.9: 9, 0.97: 1, 0.66: 6, 0.82: 5}
```

---

EDIT:

If duplicate values are present for grades in the list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pos_grade = defaultdict(list)

y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82]

i = 0
for x in y:
   if x != 0.0:
       pos_grade[x].append(i)
   i += 1

print pos_grade
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0.9: [9], 0.97: [1], 0.66: [6], 0.82: [5, 12]})
```

---

Code using `enumerate`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pos_grade = defaultdict(list)

y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82]

for i, x in enumerate(y):
   if x != 0.0:
       pos_grade[x].append(i)

print pos_grade
```

Comment: Okay... and if there are multiple instances of the same [non-zero] grade?

Comment: @TrebuchetMS, we can solve it using a list for value. I just thought of posting this code as a starting point, so that OP can figure it out further.

Comment: I'd add a note recommending `enumerate` over `i = 0; i += 1` but ok.

Comment: Thank you for the help@Jay and @TrebuchetMS ; the desired output for the question would be dic['pos'] = [1, 5, 6, 9]  dic['grds'] = [0.97, 0.82, 0.66, 0.90]

Comment: @Mac, Check the top of my post now. That should help you.

Comment: @Jay you are the man, I was able to tweak the code and it ran perfectly.

Comment: @Mac, Thanks. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @Jay done and done, although my lackluster reputation on stack flow keeps the upvote from showing

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to use dict comprehension:

```
y = [0.0, 0.97, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.82, 0.66, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90, 0.0, 0.0]
{v:k for k,v in enumerate(y) if v!=0}
```

output

```
{0.66: 6, 0.82: 5, 0.9: 9, 0.97: 1}
```

Comment: the desired output for the question would be dic['pos'] = [1, 5, 6, 9]  dic['grds'] = [0.97, 0.82, 0.66, 0.90]